# what is meaning of while(t-- >0)

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++, while-loop

In various codes where time limit exceeded, by using while(t-- >0) instead of while(t--)  code runs successfully. I don't know about while(t-- >0) , I read it somewhere in the codechef examples solution.

Comment: It's different if `t` can be negative.

Comment: The (inexistent) difference should not matter for "time limit exceeded". Something other is the reason for failing or not.

Answer (score -1):

In practice, they are equivalent. It's just a matter of taste. Some think that `while(t-- > 0)` is clearer than `while(t--)`.

As long as `t` is not negative, the two are completely equivalent. But on the other hand, a negative `t` would most likely indicate a bug with a loop like that.